# SNS Subscription Wants a String

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm trying to update my SNS subscription  with a second endpoint however I get this error
"Value of property Endpoint must be of type String"

Here is my YAML. Is there a different way to add two endpoints to the one subscription? Thanks

```
ConnectorSubscription:
Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
Properties:
  Endpoint: 
              - "https://my-endpoint-name-1"
              - "https://my-endpoint-name-2"
            
  Protocol: "https"
  TopicArn: !Ref ConnectorTopic
```

Comment: guess you'll need two subscriptions

Comment: what does cloudwatch have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

An HTTPS subscription can only have a single endpoint. You will need to **create multiple subscriptions**.

This is a very useful design. For example, let's say that one endpoint is working well while another is non-responsive. Amazon SNS will re-try the non-responsive endpoint independently to other subscriptions.